# Solving $x+x\ln(x)+\ln(x)=y$ for $x$

Tags: logarithms, problem-solving

For $x,y\in\mathbb{R^+}$ , consider the equation:

$x+x\ln(x)+\ln(x)=y$

with constant $y$,

which is the same as

$x+\ln(x^{x+1})=y$

How do I solve for $x$?

Comment: Is $y$ fixed? That looks like a function to me, not an equation

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe the answer is not "you don't"?

Comment: @Pythagorus Because even if there is a unique answer, there might be no closed form for it.  Many things in math simply don't have good answers, and so you should have a reason for looking for one.

Comment: If you want to ping someone, you need to use the exact username with "@" .like @Eric Towers (sorry for this xD). Can't mention two people

Comment: @user675453 Thanks. This is a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By differentiating, we can discover that $y$ is strictly increasing as a function of $x$, and it's easy enough to see that $y \to -\infty$ as $x \to 0$ and that $y \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$; so the function is bijective with range $\mathbb{R}$. But I'd be absolutely astonished if there were a closed form for it. Certainly Mathematica couldn't find one.